# Delphi to VB: define data types

Tags: vb.net, delphi, enums

I am migrating to VB, so I need a little help:

in Delphi I have:

```
type osVer = (
   osVerUnknown,
   osVerWin95,
   osVerWin95OSR2,
....

function GetVersion : osVer;
....
```

I need to translate to VB...
Until i'll get any help from you, i'll keep on searching the net.

thanks

Comment: PS: I want to create a module that contains some data types and functions

Comment: I can understand the other direction, but why in the world would anyone want to go *from* Delphi *to* VB?!?

Comment: Maybe they hate type safety..

Comment: @Blindy VB has type safety. What are you talking about?

Comment: It has some semblance of it, sure, if you remember to turn it on manually for every single file, and don't use variants. Personally I'd consider Java more type safe with its so-called generics "support".

Comment: @Blindy Are you thinking of VB6? That was a proverbial satchel of chaff. But VB.net is decent.

Comment: Of course, but this thread looks VB6'y to me. It's not tagged VB.NET :)

Comment: It would be utterly insane to move from Delphi to VB6! Surely it's VB.net!

Comment: What version of Visual Basic, Remus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That maps to vb's `enum` construct:

```
enum osVer
  osVerUnknown=0
  osVerWin95
  osVerWin95OSR2
  ' keep going
end enum

' and later on in your code
dim val as osVer
val=osVer.osVerWin95

' edit: as to your getversion function:
public function GetVersion() as osVer
end function
```

As a side note, this kind of OS detection... you'll be hard pressed to find an actual application for it.

Comment: Oh. Good catch! Would it surprise you if I said I caught myself before typing `;` at the end three times?

Comment: @Blindy: do you have another idea in detecting OS version (i'm using my own app to display system info)

Comment: @Remus, I'm sure the OS version detection works fine (up to some arbitrary point, bet you 30$ it doesn't support the upcoming Windows 8). My point was, it's absolutely irrelevant. If you're just presenting it to the user, consider that might know what OS they have (they paid for it after all) or they simply don't care. If *you're* using it, consider testing for features rather than for OS version (I'll direct your attention to the (missing) Win8 mention above).

Comment: @daemon, if you looked at the link in the comment you just deleted, you'd see that it stopped at windows server 2003. This manual OS detection will always be behind the curve because it's.. well.. manual.

Comment: Yes. His `GetVersion` however isn't. And hey look, the link you posted this time only goes up to XP.

Comment: OK let me reiterate my initial point. ***If you rely on a compiled in list of white-listed operating systems, you'll reach (in your lifetime) a point where you'll reject a perfectly valid operating system***. That and it's absolutely useless to even consider it...

Answer (score 1):

I've not ever used delphi, but I think I follow what you want here:

```
Public Enum osVer
   osVerUnknown
   osVerWin95
   osVerWin95OSR2
End Enum

Public Function GetVersion() As osVer
...
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not translate the intent, instead of the enumerated type.

Check this in VB.net:

```
Dim osVersion As String = System.Environment.OSVersion.ToString()

MessageBox.Show(osVersion)
```